# Efficiently generate all combinations (at all depths) whose sum is within a specified range

Tags: c#, algorithm, checksum

I have a set of 80 numbers and I would like to find the list of combinations which totals up to a given number. The below code works fine but its takes too long could someone please help me with an enhanced version which would process it faster ?

```
public void sum_up(List<int> numbers, int target)    
        {
            sum_up_recursive(numbers, target, new List<int>());
        }

        public void sum_up_recursive(List<int> numbers, int target, List<int> partial)
        {
            int s = 0;
            foreach (int x in partial) s += x;

            if (s == target)
                val +=" sum(" + string.Join(",", partial.ToArray()) + ")=" + target + Environment.NewLine;

            if (s == target && string.Join(",", partial.ToArray()).Contains("130") &&
                string.Join(",", partial.ToArray()).Contains("104"))
            {
                string gg = " sum(" + string.Join(",", partial.ToArray()) + ")=" + target;
                val += " || || sum(" + string.Join(",", partial.ToArray()) + ")=" + target + Environment.NewLine;
            }

            if (s >= target)
                return;

            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
            {
                List<int> remaining = new List<int>();
                int n = numbers[i];
                for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.Count; j++) remaining.Add(numbers[j]);

                List<int> partial_rec = new List<int>(partial);
                partial_rec.Add(n);
                sum_up_recursive(remaining, target, partial_rec);
            }
            lblResult.Text = val;                
        }

        private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string[] vendorVal = txtvendor.Text.Split(',');
            int[] myInts = Array.ConvertAll(vendorVal, s => int.Parse(s));
            List<int> numbers = myInts.ToList();
            int target = Convert.ToInt32(txtDifference.Text);
            sum_up(numbers, target);

        }
```

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: yea there can be duplicates found and the rage can vary from 0 to 5000

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Sum to target algorithm", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 2):

You recalculate the same partial sums again and again - this process takes a lot of time. If targer sum value is reasonable and you have enough memory - use dynamic programming approach.

Create array `A` of length `(TargetSum + 1)` containing lists possible variants for intermediate sums.

For every item value V make loop from sum `S=TargetSum` downto `V` (reverse traversal helps to avoid repeated using of the same item). If entry `A[S - V]` is not empty - add all variants from `A[S - V]` with addition of `V` into `A[V]`. Finally `A[TargerSum]` will contain all possible combinations.

Also consider `memoization` technique - it might be constructed from your recursive function - just remember sum variants in dictionary and reuse stored variants.